Laravel Eloquent Query Running So SLOWLY as compared to mySQL counterpart
Why is this laravel eloquent query running so SLOWLY?
I have a query running in a Laravel job that executes very slowly and inconsistently. Sometimes it takes 1-2 minutes to fetch the result, while at other times it completes in just 1-2 seconds for the same exact query.
Slow Full Eloquent Query ( Takes 1-2 minutes for the query to be completed )
$relevantRobot = App\Robot::where('serial_number', 'TEST-ID')
                    ->whereHas('robot_maps', function($query) use ($robot_map_name) {
                        $query->where('name', $robot_map_name);
                    })
                    ->with(['robot_maps' => function($query) use ($robot_map_name) {
                            $query->where('name', $robot_map_name);
                        },
                        'current_robot_position',
                        'current_robot_position.robot_map',
                        'latest_robot_deployment_information_request'
                    ])
                    ->first(); // Get the raw SQL query

Slow Reduced Eloquent Query ( Takes 1-2 minutes for the query to be completed )
$relevantRobot = App\Robot::where('serial_number', 'TEST-ID')
                    ->whereHas('robot_maps', function($query) use ($robot_map_name) {
                        $query->where('name', $robot_map_name);
                    })
                    ->with(
                        'current_robot_position',
                    ])
                    ->first(); // Get the raw SQL query

Fast Reduced Eloquent Query ( Completes in less than a second )
$relevantRobot = App\Robot::where('serial_number', 'TEST-ID')
                    ->whereHas('robot_maps', function($query) use ($robot_map_name) {
                        $query->where('name', $robot_map_name);
                    })
                    ->with(
                        'latest_robot_deployment_information_request',
                    ])
                    ->first(); // Get the raw SQL query

SQL Query ( Completes in less than a second )
select * from `robots` where `serial_number` = 'TEST-ID' and exists (select * from `robot_maps` where `robots`.`id` = `robot_maps`.`robot_id` and `name` = 'test' and `active` = 1);

Eloquent Relationship
 public function current_robot_position(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\RobotMapPositionLog','robot_id','id')
            ->orderBy('id','desc');
    }

Attempted Solution
After noticing the slow load time when eagerly loading current_robot_position, I added indexes to the columns used in that relationship (id). However, this hasn't improved the performance.
I also tried converting the Eloquent query to a raw MySQL query using toSql(), and it ran extremely fast (under 1 second).
What is wrong? What am I missing?
UPDATE
I have identified ->with('current_robot_position') to be the issue that is slowly down the entire query.
As some others have sugggested, I have made the foreign key column (robot_id) column used in the relationship an index column and also changed the orderBy with latest() but neither of this has helped reduce the load time significantly

try ->latestOfMany(); in current_robot_position and check

@AbdullaNilam I used latest() because I am running on an older version of laravel and it doesn't help

your SQL query is not the same as your eloquent, you need to test the eager loading query not the main one. The main one seems to be just as fast

also please clarify the table schema with indexes, for the related tables

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT.

Root Cause
The hasOne relationship is taking an unexpectedly long time to process, even with latest('id')/orderBy('id') applied. Although this setup is meant to return only the most recent entry, the query still scans the entire RobotMapPositionLog table, which contains hundreds of thousands of records, thus contributing to the long load times.
Solution
Simply by specifying limit(1) the load time dropped from 30seconds-1minute to it being loaded within a second
public function current_robot_position(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\RobotMapPositionLog','robot_id','id')
        ->orderBy('id','desc');
        ->latest('id')->limit(1);
}


To improve the speed of your Laravel query, try these steps:

Optimize orderBy in Relationships: Use latest('id') instead of


orderBy('id', 'desc'):
public function current_robot_position() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\RobotMapPositionLog', 'robot_id', 'id')->latest('id');
}



Add Indexes: Ensure that the robot_id columns in the robot_maps and robot_map_position_logs tables are indexed.
Use limit(1): Limit the main query to one record directly in SQL:


->limit(1)->first();



Reduce Nested Relationship Loading: Load nested relationships in two steps to avoid extra queries:


if ($relevantRobot) {
    $relevantRobot->load(['current_robot_position', 'current_robot_position.robot_map']);
}



Use Caching: Cache results for frequently accessed queries to prevent re-running the query:


Cache::remember('relevantRobot-' . $robot_map_name, now()->addMinutes(10), function() { ... });



I have determined the portion that is slowing down the query to be ->with('current_robot_position'])
With this said, as you have suggested I have followed the first 3 suggested solutions of replace orderBy with latest(), added index for robot_id but it hasn't helped with the load times.
I am not able to use cache in this situation as it should always retrieve the latest position

I think your problem comes down to having a lot of data structured in a way that isn't properly optimized for your query.
I see in your raw SQL query your robot_maps subquery is searching on the id column, which I presume is the primary key of robot_maps, but your Eloquent queries are using the name column. Even if name is indexed, your numeric primary key can be queried faster than a string.

Index robot_maps.name column, or query robots using a numeric primary key like id
Make sure robots.serial_number is indexed, or make serial_number the primary key if it's an integer or UUID. Querying by numeric primary key still preferred here.
Make sure robot_map_position_log.robot_id column is indexed (guessing the table name based on model name)

You could try lazy loading the relationships to help isolate which part of your query is the slowest.

I have determined the portion that is slowing down the query to be ->with('current_robot_position'])
With this said, as you have suggested, I have added the respective index for the robot_id column that is used in the relationship however it hasn't helped in reducing the load time.
Further more, I have also switched the orderBy query to use latest() instead but to no avail.

Okay that's progress! I have a few suggestions then:
Based on your ->hasOne(RobotMapPos...) relationship, it looks like the foreign key lives on your robot_positions table. Have you tried making this a ->belongsTo() and placing the foreign key on your robots table?
You may get away with just using a raw SQL query: DB::raw() or using a table join ->join('robot_positions as rp', 'robots.id', '=', 'rp.robot_id').
You can try using XDebug to step through the framework and see what the problem is.
You can use LaravelDebugBar and see when queries are happening to check for N+1
